# Need help finding an element in selenium

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver, element, locate

Can some one help me to locate an element (without using xpath) which is displayed using : `<i id="ext-gen759" class="icon-tool"></i>` under a `<div>` tag. The HTML is as follows:

```
<div id="ext-comp-1089" class=" MiniTbar">
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="ext-gen760" class=" active">
<i id="ext-gen759" class="icon-tool"></i>  -->> need to locate this.
</a>

</div>
```

I don't want to use:

`By.Id`  --> id is dynamic
`By.XPath`  --> not stable

I have tried the following without getting a result:

```
By.className("icon-tool") -- > not working 
By.partialLinkText("icon-tool") --> not working
```

Any solution?

Comment: Why would an XPath expression not be stable? _What_ is not stable in your input HTML? What _is_ stable and sets your targeted nodes apart from the rest?

Comment: When I use xPath, for every run it is giving me different results.. If I refresh the page and rerun the test it is not finding the actual element with xPath.. My web page displays lot of menus/popups/tooltips (on mouse hover ) and has frames in masked/unmasked states... Most of the elements are generated dynamically..

Answer (score 2):

You can rely on the part of the `id` using, for example, `starts-with()`:

```
//div[starts-with(@id, "ext-comp-")]/a[starts-with(@id, "ext-gen")]/i[@class="icon-tool"]
```

Or a *CSS selector*:

```
div[id^=ext-comp-] a.active[id^=ext-gen] i.icon-tool[id^=ext-gen]
```

Comment: But "ext-comp-"  is a generic format used in the whole document and 'icon-tool' is also used everywhere in the same document/page. So how can i pick this one element only?

Answer (score 1):

using `xpath` should do this. You may need to make sure that's the only element `i` with same criteria on the page

```
//i[contains(@id,'ext-gen')]
```

Comment: how to write a CSS selector to find an element using some part of a its classname (say some characters inside the classname)? Something similar to "contains(text())" ?

Comment: You need to provide me the `html` for that. `contains()` function does not work for css. That's an xpath function

Comment: <div id="ext-6" class="gen-border-1"">
  <div id="ext-10" class="gen-view-1">
     <div class="Item ">
      <h4>
       <i class="gen-icon-009"></i>
        Hello
        </h4>

I need to locate element with class name contains  'icon' under 3 the div.

Answer (score 1):

Give a chance to the find element by css selector ?

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('i.icon-tool')
```

The python documentation is here http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/locating-elements.html

Comment: The problem is - 'icon-tool' is being used in lots of other places in the document as well..

Comment: well you can use the find_elements to find all the i.icon-tool and iterate on the results. In any case you need a way to discriminate between the multiple results

Answer (score 0):

You can find it using css selector:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("i[class='icon-tool']"));
```